# Keep my flutter app running in background with a notification

Tags: android, ios, flutter, notifications, background

I have been developing an Flutter app for glider pilots for the past few weeks.

The principle is simple : detect whenever the pilots takes-off and when he lands, then store this data for further use.
The detection is started when the user pushes a RaisedButton and it works like this :

*1. Check the ground speed, if not above a certain limit, wait 30 seconds and go back to 1. Else, continue.*

*2. Check the vertical speed, if not above a certain limit, wait 30 seconds and go back to 1. Else, the device is considered flying so the current time is saved in a variable and try detecting the landing (3).*

*3. If the ground speed is above 0, wait 30 seconds and go back to 3. Else, continue.*

*4. Check the vertical speed, if it is equal to 0, then the landing happened so the current time is saved. Else, wait 30 seconds and go back to 3.*

*5. Return the take-off time and landing time.*

It works well. But only in when the app is running.
Obviously, when the app is dismissed, the process is stopped and so the detection is. To avoid the user exiting the app while trying to detect a flight, I wrapped the app in an WillPopScope that returns a confirmation popup whenever the user pushed the back button if the detection is still running.

But when the user switches to an other app, the process continues for some random time, and then it is terminated by the OS.

I read some articles on medium like this one : https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/%EF%B8%8F-the-tricky-task-of-keeping-flutter-running-on-android-2d51bbc60882 but I don't know if this is what I need to do (and actually, I don't fully understand it).

I would like to do something like the Messenger app from Facebook : display a permanent notification to keep the app alive and detecting the flight times when the user locked the screen or uses an other app. I have an other example of app that does this : XCSoar (it'a GPS navigation app that also cannot accept to be killed during the flight, and there is a notification like on Messenger).

I would like to know if it is possible to do this for both Android and iOS ad I plan to deploy the app on both platforms. But for now, if it just works for Android, it's perfectly fine.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It isn't possible on iOS.

Comment: So how is it possible to some message apps to fetch new messages while not opened ?
And how is it possible to do it on android ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Android really, but on IOS an app cannot add a window to the screen permanently.  Apps can display push and local notification messages for short times.  On iOS you can disable the auto lock and you can check the external power state, so you might like to disable the auto lock while your app is running and maybe display a warning alert if they aren't on external power.

Comment: What sensors are you using in your app?  If the user switches out of your app, Core Motion updates stop being delivered until the user returns.  GPS based updates can be delivered while your app is in the background, so if you are using the GPS you may not even have an issue.

Comment: I am using GPS information.
The problem I'm facing is that the OS kills the app after a while if the user is not using it, and I can't accept that when it is running this specific part of the code.

Comment: I don't know about Flutter but with native code as long as you enable your Core Location session for background updates you will receive location updates every second even if you are in the background. You shouldn't do this indefinitely as it will use a lot of battery but it shouldn't be a problem for the duration of a flight.

Comment: So it's definitely not possible to continue executing my code started by the onPressed in my RaisedButton when the app is terminated by the OS ?

Comment: As I said, I don't know how flutter apps are structured, but what you need to do when the person taps the button is start GPS location updates. These location updates are delivered, asynchronously to your code (on iOS they are delivered to a delegate method called `didUpdateLocations`). You may need to research how to use location in flutter.

Comment: Actually, the process works : I am able to get the location updates, but not to keep the app alive. I am actually trying to use this package to make it work on Android : https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/foreground_notification
For iOS, I don't know

Comment: What I am saying is that if you do it right then you don't need to "keep the app alive". If you configure the location manager correctly then location updates are delivered while the app is in the background. No special "hack" is required. When you receive each location update you can examine the ground speed and compute the vertical speed based on the previous location data.

Comment: For example, [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocation) claims to support background location mode.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look into this. But does this mean that I'll be able to execute code each time I get location updates, as an example save the data in local sqlite database if my code says that the location data received means that the device is not in flight anymore ?

Comment: Yes. You get a few seconds execution time each time there is a location update.

Comment: Well I think that you found exactly what I need.
I'll rewrite my code with this plugin then.
Thanks a lot :)